# Articles and vowels a,e,i,u,o, question about a & o & e

Tags: grammar, articles

I have some problems with articles and vowels: a,e,u,i,o.
Some days ago my teacher told me if you want to use article with *university*, you have to use *a university* not *an university*.
He even told me it works even for *o and e*.
He named this knowledge Phonology and Phonetic. Could you explain this please.

---

Thanks

Comment: The letters **a, e, i, o, u** are **vowels**, not articles.  The words **a, an** and **the** are articles. We use **an** before a word starting with a vowel _sound_ (an apple), but not with words like _union_ and _university_ because they are pronounced as though they began with a 'y' - _'yunion'_.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an for a full answer. Your teacher seems to be saying that some words that begin with u and some that begin with o take the article a instead of an (such as a university, a onesie), is that right? I can also think of some e words that do the same (a euphonium, a euro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a confusion here between *vowel letters* and *vowel sounds*. The English vowel letters are "a, e, i, o, and u". The English vowel sounds are represented with these symbols: /i/, /ɪ/, /u/, /ʊ/, /e/, /ɛ/, /ə/, /ɜ/, /o/, /ɔ/, /ʌ/, /æ/, /a/, /ɑ/ and /ɒ/.

As you can see, English has many more vowel sounds than vowel letters, so, unlike many other languages, English letters don't always have the same sound.

The rule about "a" and "an" only works with *vowel sounds*, not with vowel letters.

Although the first *letter* of "university" is "u", the word is pronounced /,ju:nɪ'vɜrsəti/, and as you can see, the first *sound* in the word is not one of the vowel sounds, but rather the consonant sound /j/.

Words that start with "u" can have "an" before them if the first sound is a vowel sound, as in "an umbrella".

Also, some words that start with consonant letters ("consonant" means non-vowel) are pronounced with a vowel sound first, like "hour", which is pronounced: /aʊər/ -- the "h" is not pronounced at all. These words take "an", not "a": "*an hour*".

Comment: Thank you so much❤